# React - Using useState to delete and re-render array of images

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've recently started learning React and I want try using `useState`. I'm having an issue where the page is not rendering after image has been clicked and deleted from the array of image links.

Here is my code

```
import data from './assets/data/images.json'
import { useState } from 'react'

function App() {

  var defaultList = Object.values(data)
  const [image, removeImage] = useState(defaultList)
  
  const callback = (key) => {
    console.log("removed image: ", defaultList[key])
    delete defaultList[key]
    removeImage(defaultList)
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.App}>
      
      <div className={styles.ImageExamples}>
        {
          image.map((v, k) => {
            return <a onClick={() => callback(k)}><img src={v}/></a>
          })
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

To test this, you will need `images.json`

```
{
    "0": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1696399744120-da551393c12f?w=600&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxjb2xsZWN0aW9uLXBhZ2V8Nnw0NjU0NzMxfHxlbnwwfHx8fHw%3D",
    "1": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1622532824228-e1dffce3f265?w=600&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxjb2xsZWN0aW9uLXBhZ2V8M3wxNjYzMjQwfHxlbnwwfHx8fHw%3D",
    "2": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542652735873-fb2825bac6e2?w=600&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxjb2xsZWN0aW9uLXBhZ2V8OXwxNjYzMjQwfHxlbnwwfHx8fHw%3D",
    "3": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472656877636-35a4bb852385?w=600&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxjb2xsZWN0aW9uLXBhZ2V8MjB8MTU4ODI1fHxlbnwwfHx8fHw%3D",
    "4": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614364655846-cd8087a5b38b?w=600&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxjb2xsZWN0aW9uLXBhZ2V8NDh8MTU4ODI1fHxlbnwwfHx8fHw%3D"
}
```

When I click on the images, the console shows that the image has been deleted from the array, however the `useState` doesn't rerender the page once the image has been clicked. The changes only show up, after I made some changes to the code, saved it, removed the changes and saved it again.

Comment: Take a look at this article about updating objects & arrays in React: https://dev.to/andyrewlee/cheat-sheet-for-updating-objects-and-arrays-in-react-state-48np

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Updating Arrays in State](https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state) documentation:

> Arrays are mutable in JavaScript, but you should treat them as immutable when you store them in state. Just like with objects, when you want to update an array stored in state, you need to create a new one (or make a copy of an existing one), and then set state to use the new array.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const data = {
  '0': 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1696399744120-da551393c12f?w=600&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxjb2xsZWN0aW9uLXBhZ2V8Nnw0NjU0NzMxfHxlbnwwfHx8fHw%3D',
  '1': 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1622532824228-e1dffce3f265?w=600&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxjb2xsZWN0aW9uLXBhZ2V8M3wxNjYzMjQwfHxlbnwwfHx8fHw%3D',
  '2': 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542652735873-fb2825bac6e2?w=600&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxjb2xsZWN0aW9uLXBhZ2V8OXwxNjYzMjQwfHxlbnwwfHx8fHw%3D',
  '3': 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472656877636-35a4bb852385?w=600&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxjb2xsZWN0aW9uLXBhZ2V8MjB8MTU4ODI1fHxlbnwwfHx8fHw%3D',
  '4': 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614364655846-cd8087a5b38b?w=600&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxjb2xsZWN0aW9uLXBhZ2V8NDh8MTU4ODI1fHxlbnwwfHx8fHw%3D',
};

function App() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(Object.values(data));

  const callback = (index: number) => {
    setImage((pre) => pre.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {image.map((v, index) => {
        return (
          <a onClick={() => callback(index)}>
            <img src={v} />
          </a>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-hoicsm?file=src%2FApp.tsx)

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain this part of the code -

const callback = (index: number) => {
    setImage((pre) => pre.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
  };

Comment: @Neptunas Remove an element from an array by its index and return a new array